# matlab - cellfun sum all elements of each cell

Tags: matlab

Hi I have populated a cell array using:

```
D(i) = {dist};

D = reshape(D, w, h)
```

so that if i have:

```
 pix1 = D{1,1};   
 pix2 = D{2,2};
```

I get

```
pix1 = 
    1 2 3

pix2 =
    4 5 6
```

What I want to do is sum all the elements in each pix, and then take those results and form a matrix i.e.

```
sum(pix1) = 6
sum(pix2) = 15

matrix = 
    6 15
```

where in this case matrix is a 1X2 matrix (mine is a lot larger).

I am trying to do this using:

```
field = cellfun(@(dist) sum(dist(:)), D,'UniformOutput', false);
```

but this just gives me a matrix full of NaN's. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {[1 2 4], [4 5 6]};
B = cellfun(@sum, A)
```

results in

<del>B = [6 15]</del>

```
B = [7 15]
```

Comment: what if I have a 2x2 cell array? ie

A = [1X3 double] [1x3 double] \n [1x3 double] [1x3 double]


the code you have posted doesn't appear to work for this example, how would i alter your code to work on a 2x2 cell array? or nxn even? thanks for your reply.

Comment: @brucezepplin: are you sure? it works just fine. Example: `A = {[1 2 4], [4 5 6]; [1 2 4], [4 5 6]};` then `B = cellfun(@sum, A)`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have `NaN`s in your cells and you wish to ignore them you may use [`nansum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nansum.html):

```
A = {[1, 2, NaN], [3, NaN, 4, 5]; [6, NaN], [10, -3, NaN, 4]};
B = cellfun( @nansum, A )
```

Results with

```
B =

    3    12
    6    11
```